# How to create better WP_Query to look for date time which is anywhere between two meta values?

Tags: wp-query, meta-query

The following arguments are used for `WP_Query` to check if a reservation for a game can be created.
Meta input fields for post are created using `ACF DateTime Picker` and set to `Y-m-d H:i:s`

```
$start_date = '2019-08-31 12:15:00';
$end_date = '2019-08-31 12:20:00';

$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'rezervacija',
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'meta_query' => array(
        'relation' => 'AND',
        array(
            'relation' => 'OR',
            array(
                'key' => 'start_date',
                'value' => array($start_date, $end_date),
                'compare' => 'BETWEEN',
                'type' => 'DATETIME'
                ),
            array(
                'key' => 'end_date',
                'value' => array($start_date, $end_date),
                'compare' => 'BETWEEN',
                'type' => 'DATETIME'
                )
            ),
        array(
            'key' => 'location', // Look also for specific playground, not important for this question
            'value' => 3,
            'compare' => '='
            )
        )
    );

$query = new WP_Query($args);
```

This code generally works, but not fully as expected.
If there is already reservation created with a start date set to 12:00 (`2019-08-31 12:00:00`) and end time 14:00 (`2019-08-31 14:00:00`) and then if a new user selects time 12:15, and end time 13:30, in that case since it looks for those values separately the query won't find anything but it should.  So generally this query won't find data properly when the time is somewhere inside of previous reservation times.

How can I modify this query to search for posts whose $start_date and $end_date are anywhere between values start_date and end_date?

Comment: That location meta key looks like it could be a custom taxonomy instead, which would be orders of magnitude faster. Look up in the ACF docs how to use a taxonomy rather than post meta as the storage for a field. Otherwise avoid searching for posts using post meta values at all costs, it's stupendously slow/expensive and not what post meta was designed for

Comment: Thanks, I have researched a little about this, although this is an older website I will pay attention in the future projects.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to do this for querying between two dates:

```
$query = new WP_Query(array(
                        'post_type' => 'rezervacija',
                        'posts_per_page' => -1,
                        'post_status' => 'publish',
                        'meta_query' => array(
                                'relation' => 'AND',
                                array(
                                    'key'     => 'start_date',
                                    'value'   => current_time('Ymd'), //change this according to your need.
                                    'compare' => '>=',
                                ),
                                array(
                                    'key'     => 'end_date',
                                    'value'   => current_time('Ymd'), //change this according to your need.
                                    'compare' => '<=',
                                ),

                            ),
                    ));

    if ($query->have_posts()) : 
        while($query->have_posts()) : 
            $query->the_post();
            the_permalink(); 
            the_title();
        endwhile;  
    endif;
```

Comment: It is not working for time in-between two times like I stated in the question but also it seems that it is not working when only one time is inside of previous reservations so in that case my example works slightly better..